# why does regex with \[ not work

Tags: regex

i try to read vallid url from a document with regex, but it doesnt work as i expect
i got this regex

```
https?:\/\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=\[\]]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\ +.~#?&//=]*)
```

but if i try to read for example "https://www.example.com/folder/folder/document.pdf" it works,
but if i try to read "https://www.example.com/folder/folder/document[first attempt].pdf" it doesnt match.
debugger says : 
    "\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)"

**FYI:** i tried in on http://regexr.com/

Comment: `/` does not have to be doubled in a character class, one is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just to add `\[\]`

```
https?:\/\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=\[\]]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9\[\]@:%_\ +.~#?&//=]*)
```

You can find some interesting url matching regex [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/2037229)

Comment: that works but.., thats in the part after the dot ?
why does it have to be there too ?

Comment: because, the first class does not contains `/` hence the dot will match the last dot in the domain name but not the dot of the file extension

Comment: thank you for the explaination :-) , maybe i should thurn the aircondition a little lower